# Unable to create an ec2 instance using boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am not able to create an EC2 instance using boto3.

I am trying to create an instance using boto3.

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
ec2.create_instances(ImageId='ami-0d8f6eb4f641ef691', MinCount=1, MaxCount=1, InstanceType='t2.micro')
```

My region is US East(Ohio)

I am not sure how to find the AMI to a specific region. I just selected what was available.

The error message is

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidAMIID.NotFound) when calling the RunInstances operation: The image id '[ami-0d8f6eb4f641ef691]' does not exist
```

and I copied the AMI ID from the:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing the region_name parameter.

You can set the region_name is your code as:

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-east-2')
```

Hope it helps.